# Counting lines containing each substring present in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I wrote this code for finding a sub-string (of length **`k`**) in a string. I expect it to check through 466 strings (from a file opened through **`pc`**) and if a sub-string is present add `1` to the sub-string dictionary `proteinCDict`, thus basically counting in how many sequences does a sub-string occur. Apparently it is not working:

```
import operator

proteinCDict = {}
for i in range(0, 466):
    record = []
    pc.readline()
    sequence = pc.readline()
    for j in range(0, len(sequence)-k):
        if((sequence[j:j+k] in proteinCDict) and\
           (sequence[j:j+k] not in record)):
            record.append(sequence[j:j+k])
            proteinCDict[sequence[j:j+k]] += 1
        else:
            record.append(sequence[j:j+k])
            proteinCDict[sequence[j:j+k]] = 1

proteinCDict =  sorted(proteinCDict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
print(proteinCDict)
```

The problem I'm facing is illustrated through a particular case when k=7, the sub-string with highest frequency of occurrence is lower than when k=8. This should not be  the case since the sub-string with highest frequency in k=8 can be divided into two sub-strings of length 7. So where am I going wrong?

**EDIT:** Every alternate line is a space hence I'm calling `readline()` 2 times.

Comment: You inspect only every other line, because you call `readline()` twice for each iteration, but save the returned value only once. Is that intentional? Also, where do you define `record`?

Comment: @DyZ clarification about that, every other line is a space thus not required

Comment: Please add an example of your input file; just to be safe.

Comment: @DyZ well how can there be values returned at all if it is a blank space? My output is returning some values just not following the trend I expect it to

Comment: A space is as good as any other value. But what is `record`?

Comment: @DyZ added it..Somehow it got removed while copy paste

Answer (score 3):

First, a few comments on your code:

- The main issue I see is that by looping over `range(0, len(sequence)-k)`, you are skipping the subsequence `sequence[len(sequence)-k:]`.
- If you are to open a file, you should use a `with` statement.
- Instead of using a `range`, you can directly iterate over your file object to get its lines.
- For anything related to counting, a `collections.Counter` is probably better suited.
- To track which subsequence have been seen on a single line, a `set` is a better suited data strucutre than a `list` as it allows constant time lookup.

The following solution uses a `Counter`, you can then use `Counter.most_common` to sort the subsequences by number of appearances.

### Code

```
import collections

def count_in_file(filename, k):
    counter = collections.Counter()

    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()

            line_sequences = set(line[i:i+k] for i in range(len(line) + 1 - k))

            for seq in line_sequences:
                counter[seq] += 1

    return counter

counter = count_in_file('test_file.txt', 3)

print(counter.most_common())
```

### Test file

```
ABCABC

BCA
```

### Output

```
[('BCA', 2), ('CAB', 1), ('ABC', 1)]
```

Comment: You didn't understand my problem properly..But your code will give BCD=3 if the first sequence is abcdbcd whereas I want it to be 2

Comment: @DuttaA So what you want is to count the number of lines that contain each sequence?

Comment: @DuttaA Also, please don't handwave our misunderstandings. There are a few people here that are putting energy and time trying to understand your question which is not the clearest. While I like doing so, please be respectful of those efforts.

Comment: I didn't show any disrespect..But then that's your viewpoint. Coming to the code although your code is working I wanted to know where did my code go wrong...also how to sort the output?

Comment: @DuttaA It's fine, I was just mentionning it, if you did not intend to be disrespectful, then no harm done. As for you code, it's hard to know as I cannot test it since pc is assigned outside the provided code. Although, one major difference between your code and mine is that you use `range(0, len(sequence)-k)`, while I use `range(0, len(sequence)-k+1)`, you are probably losing a few subsequences due to that. Finally, how do you want the subsequence sorted, by most common?

Comment: As I said, I cannot test your code, to help us answer, please read about providing [minimal complete verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As for sorting, see the edit, you can use Counter.most_common

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at the logic for now,

you should do something like `j:j+k-1`
since j's first position is always 0.

I would suggest setting a variable for the new end position such as `endpos = j+k-1` and use that instead

Also, if the substring you seek is in `proteinCDict`, you shouldn't append it anymore. You just need to seek it as you have done.

Comment: I don't know about your last paragraph..But changing to j+k-1 will help me how?

Comment: j's first position is 0, so for example, to get 'talk' out of 'talksoon', where k=4, end position of k needs to be 3.

Comment: Ummm... I don't think string splicing in python works that way..Try it out on your ipython console..The last position is not included

Comment: oohh... yea haha :)